# Can I search for items in list of objects without a for loop?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Not sure if this is possible or not, but I'm using sqlalchemy and my queries returns all the items as objects.  I want to search for items within that list of objects but not have to do a for loop each time.

Here's how I know now to currently do it:

```
for x in objects_from_query:
    print x.name, ' - ', x.age
```

if I want to find out if I have data for a user named 'bob' in my list I would have to:

```
for x in objects_from_query:
    if x.name == 'bob':
        print 'bob exists!'
```

Because I have to do this a lot, I'm wondering if there's a faster way to find if bob exists without having to do a for loop every time? Typically with lists I do something like  objects_from_query.index("bob") but is there something similar when instead of a normal list, its a list of objects?

Comment: Why don't you get SQLAlchemy to query directly so that it only returns the objects you're interested in?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I guess it doesn't make sense with my example but my real query is pulling data related to a single user and I'm trying to cross reference some data they enter against the data I already have.  I thought my large query would be hard with SQLAlchemy compared to just getting all their current data and comparing against.  I might be wrong so I'll test your idea, it does sound interesting.

Comment: "The rule of thumb for any application is to let the DB do the things it does well: filtering, sorting, and joining." Check this answer: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2324050/is-it-better-to-filter-a-resultset-using-a-where-clause-or-using-application-cod

Comment: Either do it with SQL or do all your checks in a single loop, instead of looping once for each check. Consider using a `set`.

Comment: @hectorg87 cool..I am not that good with databases but okay with python so I guess I was a bit lazy and trying to do in python that I guess the database should do(I find python more transparent so I feel i understand how it works better). I'll take the DB approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using sqlalchemy, you can use the [`.filter`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) method on the [Query](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html) object, which translates to SQL as a where clause. Something like the following would work:-

```
    import sqlalchemy as sql

    session = sql.orm.sessionmaker( bind=sql.create_engine( 'sqlite:///sql.db' ) )
    Bob = session.query( Names ).filter( Names.name == "bob" )
```

Comment: interesting..this is like Daniel Roseman's idea but is it possible to pass a list to filter? like what if I have 10 names?

Comment: I truncated the example (from some code I had) for simplicity. I'll add some links in a second to relevant sqlalchemy docs

Comment: Thats okay, I can find it if it exists.I just wasn't sure if I could do it..This would be much better for me. Although I guess I'm stuck with for loop each item, it'll be less data to go though..thanks.

Comment: The .filter methods are constructing the the SQL, and each returns another query object, so you can add more filter methods.

Comment: I find with SQLalchemy that when you want to use a lot of information from a database, but separated into subsets, it's quickest to do a single SQL query and the iterate / filter the results as you originally suggest. It can be much quicker to access python objects than to do another SQL query. If you'll only be needing a very specific subset of the database for the whole run of the application (like checking a password for a specific user at login), then use strict SQL filters..

Comment: I'll play around with both approach and see which one I like. By the way, I think the command you were referring to you in called 'in filter', its like a where clause but accepts a list.

Answer (score 2):

Answer : no . You need a loop, whatever data structure you use, from van Emde Boas , arrays, heaps, etc.

This is why you should learn programming: in order to be able to find a data structure, such that the for loop to find what you need as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2):

How about a filter to get all objects with the name bob, like:

```
filter(lambda x: x.name == 'bob', objects_from_query)
```

This still probably runs a loop underneath, but if you're looking for a more concise way of writing it, this is pretty OK.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really talk about the first one, but for the second one, something like this could really speed up the approach

```
print(x.name == 'bob' in objects_from_query)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class thing():
...   name = ""
...   age = 0
...
>>> [x.age for x in l if x.name == "bob"]
[1]
```

[List comprehension.](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)